# Winsock client latency not proportional to server latency

Tags: c++, networking, asynchronous, network-programming, winsock2

I have a [Winsock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740673(v=vs.85).aspx) client that sends 1GB of data to a Winsock server in chunks of 4MB. The client and server application use a library that is built on top of Winsock2 and uses IOCP threads.

For each of the 4MB transfers, the server does some work and sends back a response to the client.

[image: client server communication]

The client sends 256 such 4MB requests using overlapped socket IO.

**The Problem**: When `DoWork()` on the server returns immediately, the whole process takes just 9 seconds to complete; but when `DoWork()` takes 500ms, the whole 1GB transfer process takes a whooping 130 seconds!

Shouldn't the client latency be proportional to the server latency? That is, if the server takes 500 ms to do its job, shouldn't the whole process have completed in 9.5 seconds? What could be the potential bottlenecks that are causing this disproportionate increase in running time?

Comment: (245 chunks * 500 ms ) / 1000 = 122 seconds . Is not corresponding to what you should expect? The work seems to be serial and not parallel :)

Comment: Just some quick math. forgetting about any of the TCPIP transmit time. 256 * 500ms = 128s . Seems that is in the neightborood with what you are seeing. Transmission of the data is negligible compared to half a second to process. If all 256 chunks are sent simultaneously then it would seem your processing is not being done in parallel

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Somewhere the code must be serially invoking the DoWork(). Will check this. Thanks!